# Evaluate congruences with non-prime divisor with Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I can evaluate $ 17^{2012}\bmod13$ with Fermat's little theorem because $13$ is a prime number. (Fermat's Little theorem says $a^{p-1}\bmod p\equiv1$.)
But what if when I need to evaluate for example $12^{1729}\bmod 36$? in this case, $36$ is not a prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is slightly trivial, because already $12^2\equiv0\bmod36$. If the base and modulus were coprime, you could use [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem). In cases in between, where the base contains some but not all factors of the modulus, you can reduce by the common factors and then apply Euler's theorem.

Comment: What if it's $17^1729$ ?

Comment: @xiamx: I presume you meant $17^{1729}$. (You need to enclose the exponent in braces to group it, since only the first object after the circumflex is interpreted as the exponent.) In that case, since $17$ and $36$ are coprime, as stated in the answer you can apply Euler's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

This one's easy:

$$12^1=12=12\pmod{36}\;\;,\;\;12^2=144=0\pmod{36}\,...\,12^n=0\pmod{36}\,\,,\,n\geq 2$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\rm\ n\ge2\:\Rightarrow\:ab^2\:|\:(ab)^2\:|\:(ab)^n$ so $\rm\:36\:|\:12^n\,$ via $\rm\:a,b = 4,3.$